# Evaluation of this integral.

Tags: calculus, integration

What is the result of this integration in a closed form?

$ \int{\cos{ x }^2}dx $

We can say $\int { cos\left( 2x \right) dx= } \frac { sin(x) }{ 2 } $

So why we can't say $\int { cos({ x }^{ 2 })dx=\frac { sin({ x }^{ 2 }) }{ 2x }  } $

Comment: There is no closed form solution http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral+of+cos(x%5E2)

Comment: Perhaps if you apply the reverse chain rule differentiation.

Comment: The integral $\int \cos (x^2)\,dx$ is not "elementary".  A more precise term than "closed form".

Answer (score 1):

This is (essentially by definition) equal to 
$$\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}} C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi }} x\right),$$ where $C$ stands for the [Fresnel cosine integral.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral)

Comment: ...and some would consider this "closed form" after all.

Comment: @GEdgar yes, which is why I gave this as an answer. Implicit in this is the observation that the function can not be written in elementary terms, otherwise it would not have a name all its own...

Comment: Please check the edit. @IgorRivin

Answer (score 0):

The reason that $\displaystyle \int\cos(x^2)\,dx\neq \frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x}+C$ because

$$\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{\sin(x^2)}{2x}\right)=\frac{2x(\cos(x^2)\cdot 2x)-\sin(x^2)\cdot 2}{(2x^2)}\neq \cos(x^2),$$

which can be easily seen by looking at $x=0$.